# Gradle uses latest version of TestNG instead of declared version

Tags: java, gradle, testng

In my gradle script I have following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version:'3.9.1'
compile group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '2.2.4'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.6.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.6.2'
compile group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version:'1.1.4'
compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version:'4.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name:'commons-math3', version: '3.6.1'
testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version:'6.14.3'
testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.25'}
```

As seen here I ask to use 6.14.3 as the testng version. Only when I try to run my script I get the issue:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
```

I first checked if the Java version is correct, but no issues there. Only if i run gradle --debug. I found that testng jar downloaded was of version 7.0.0-beta4. But as I did not declare this I'm not sure why this is used or I can force to use the correct one?

Comment: What do you see from `gradlew dependencies`? Does it show the wrong version anywhere?

Comment: when doing gradle dependencies it show following: org.testng:testng:6.14.3 -> 7.0.0-beta4

Comment: The [answer by Chriki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55600495/6395627) seems on the right track. Note another option (probably) to declaring another `compile` dependency is to use a [resolution strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html).

Comment: @Slaw: that would be overkill, wouldn’t it? ;-)

Comment: @Chriki Not sure why? I was under the impression this situation is exactly why one would use a resolution strategy. It'd just be one `force`. But I'm not an expert in Gradle by any means.

Comment: @Slaw: you’re right, “overkill” might be the wrong term in this case. Actually I believe that my proposed solution should be more correct: it seems that the OP’s (main) code depends on the specific TestNG version since the compilation fails with the latest version. Hence he should make this compile-time dependency explicit instead of relying on it to come in through a transitive dependency via ReportNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `./gradlew dependencies` should show you the following `compile` dependencies (amongst many others):

```
…
+--- org.uncommons:reportng:1.1.4
|    +--- org.testng:testng:[5.0,) -> 7.0.0-beta6
|    \--- velocity:velocity:1.4
|         \--- velocity:velocity-dep:1.4
…
```

In other words, your declared `compile` dependency on `org.uncommons:reportng:1.1.4` has a transitive dependency on TestNG which Gradle resolves to the latest TestNG version – since you don’t explicitly declare any other TestNG dependency *for the `compile` configuration*. Note that you only directly depend on TestNG from *the `testCompile` configuration*!

You should be able to fix this by changing your TestNG dependency declaration as follows:

```
compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version:'6.14.3'
```